# Find optimal model for data

Tags: regression, data-science, least-squares

I'm struggling with a data science problem. I don't even know how to describe it concisely, so I want to explain what I'm looking for and probably many smart people here can point me in the right direction.

I have a lot of data points organized in a matrix (products in rows with variants in columns)

E.g.:

| product | price of variant 0 | price of variant 1 | price of variant 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 230 | 250 | 260 |
| B | 170 | 190 | 200 |
| C | 300 | 310 | 320 |

There are roughly 40 variants and roughly 2000 products.

**I now want to fit a model into that data which looks like this:**

***variant_price(product, variant) = base_price(product) + markup(variant)***

Results I am looking for:

- base price of each product
- markups for each variant

Constraints:

- The markups for all variants are the same across all products
- The base price is calculated per product

I feel this would be possible with a linear regression / least squares of some sort but I struggle to figure out how to even structure / begin this.

Comment: What should be the result in this case? Do you search for minimal base price for product and maximal markups for variants?

Comment: @AndrejKesely I have added the wanted results to my description

Answer (score 0):

Start by applying simple ML-models (linear regression, decision tree, SVM) and evaluate the model performance afterward (scikit-learn is a good point to start). Once you find a model which performs well, fine-tune the hyperparameters of this model (e.g. with grid search).